# bing api search

Tags: php, curl, bing-api

I am trying to search some images with bing api key.
I wrote this code but it don't work, and it not return some error.
I think it is an api error...can you help me?

```
$accountKey = 's+s/s=';
$rootUri = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search';

// Get the query. Default to 'sushi'.
$query = ($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : 'sushi';

// Get the service operation. Default to Web.
$serviceOp = ($_GET['sop']) ? $_GET['sop'] : 'Web';

// Get the market. Default to en-us.
$market = ($_GET['market']) ? $_GET['market'] : 'en-us';

$ServiceRootURL =  'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/SearchWeb/';  
$WebSearchURL = $ServiceRootURL . 'Web?$format=json&Query=';

$request = $WebSearchURL . urlencode( '\'' . $query. '\'');
echo $request;
//$requestUri = "$rootUri/$serviceOp?\$format=json&Query=$query&Market=$market";

$process = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD,  $accountKey . ":" . $accountKey);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$response = curl_exec($process);
$jsonobj = json_decode($response);
echo "<br>Ris = ".$jsonobj;
```

Comment: at least print/log what the cur_exec is returning. The HTTP code itself.

Comment: You didn't send your api key, so the request is 401 unauthorized.

Comment: how can I send it?thanks

Comment: I use     curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD,  $accountKey . ":" . $accountKey);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just jump into [the documentation](https://skydrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=9C9479871FBFA822!112&app=Word&authkey=!ANNnJQREB0kDC04) and you can use `file_get_contents` instead of cURL.

```
<?php
$accountKey = 'xxxxx';

$auth = base64_encode("$accountKey:$accountKey");

$data = array(
  'http'            => array(
  'request_fulluri' => true,
  'ignore_errors'   => true,
  'header'          => "Authorization: Basic $auth")
);

$context   = stream_context_create($data);
$query     = isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : 'sushi';
$serviceOp = isset($_GET['sop']) ? $_GET['sop'] : 'Web';
$market    = isset($_GET['market']) ? $_GET['market'] : 'en-us';

$ServiceRootURL = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/';  
$WebSearchURL   = $ServiceRootURL . 'Web?$format=json&Query=';

$request = $WebSearchURL . urlencode( '\'' . $query. '\'');

// Get the response from Bing.
$response = file_get_contents($request, 0, $context);
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: The authorization type you provided is not supported. Only Basic and OAuth are supported this error is returned with your and mine script.....

Comment: @michele Have you updated the `$accountKey` with yours? Btw, the `ServiceRootURL` you are using is wrong, it should end up with `Search` instead of `SearchWeb`.

Comment: thanks, url was incorrect!